# Can someone explain me this syntax in Angular form #name="ngModel"

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I created a template form using Angular and I wanted to show a message if the field is not correct.

Here is the input :

```
<input type="text" id="task-libelle" name="libelle" class="form__input" ngModel required>
```

And here is the error message :

```
<p class="error-message" *ngIf="libelle.invalid || libelle.pristine">This field must not be empty</p>
```

Like this, I have an error message which tells me that "libelle" does not exist on type "MyComponent".

In order to make it work, I had to add `ngModel #libelle="ngModel"`

```
<input type="text" id="task-libelle" name="libelle" class="form__input" ngModel #libelle="ngModel" required>
```

But I have no idea why and what does exactly do this #libelle="ngModel" with the ngModel attribute still be here (if i remove the ngModel attribute, I get an error NG8003: No directive found with exportAs 'ngModel').

Can someone explain this to me please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `#name` is a template reference.

you can now use it in your template as an object representing the html element:

```
<div #name> 123 </div>
<p> {{ name.innerHTML }} </p>
```

that works fine if you want the html element.

In template forms, you would prefer to get the a reference of the `FormControl` to be able to read the form control's state. you do so by using `#name="ngModel"`

```
  <input #name="ngModel" type="text" name="required" required />
  <p> is control valid: {{ name.valid }} </p>
```

in the above example, we have an input with a `required` validator. the element will be considered invalid as long as it does not contain any text.

read more: https://angular.io/guide/forms#show-and-hide-validation-error-messages

Answer (score 1):

`<input #libelle ...>` would create a local variable named `libelle` that provides access to the `input` element instance in data-binding and event-binding expressions in the HTML template

`<input ngModel #libelle="ngModel" ...>` does pretty much the same thing except it provides access to the `ngModel` directive rather than the `input` element.

The general syntax is `#localvar[="directiveName"]`.

*See documentation: https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables*